# How to use CryptoAPI to sign certificate?

Tags: vb.net, cryptography, certificate, digital-signature, hsm

I am new for developing CryptoAPI with signing certificate in VB. My old system uses emvtool.exe to sign the certificate with Luna CA3 and HSM. For example, get keys, format data and sign the certificate. I read all the files about CryptoAPI and CSR workflow. I need to redesign the format data and signing parts. I am totally lost on how to use CryptoAPI instead of emvtool.exe.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the CryptoAPI in Windows, however, I believe if you have the Luna driver installed on the machine, you most likely have a "Crypto Provider" listed in Windows for the HSM. This is useful in interfacing with the HSM when performing some Windows crypto operations. So I'd dig into the CryptoAPI and whenever there's mention of a parameter for the crypto provider, use the Luna's provider.

Comment: Thanks@Wesley, yes, I must use CSP to working with Luna. I am reading and leaning this section, but all of the codes I can find online were write by C/C++. I need the code of VB.